# Sending custom headers in JsonServiceClient for Android?

Tags: android, servicestack

I need to send custom headers in my android app, I'm using the servicestack plugin for android studio http://docs.servicestack.net/java-add-servicestack-reference

In the net.servicestack.client.JsonServiceClient class exists the field
**public static Connection Filter GlobalRequestFilter**, Can I use it for send custom headers? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set HTTP Headers on the `AndroidServiceClient` instance with:

```
AndroidServiceClient client = new AndroidServiceClient(baseUrl);
client.RequestFilter = new ConnectionFilter() {
    @Override
    public void exec(HttpURLConnection conn) {
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-header", "value");
    }
};
```

Java 8:

```
client.GlobalRequestFilter = conn -> conn.setRequestProperty("X-header", "value");
```

Or globally to all Service Client requests with:

```
AndroidServiceClient.GlobalRequestFilter = new ConnectionFilter() {
    @Override
    public void exec(HttpURLConnection conn) {
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-header", "value");
    }
};
```

Java 8:

```
AndroidServiceClient.GlobalRequestFilter = conn -> 
    conn.setRequestProperty("X-header", "value");
```